# jQuery: циклическое удаление и добавление одного и того же элемента с содержимым

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Задача: посредством `jQuery` добиться того, чтобы на на одних диапазонах ширин окна `div` удалялся, на других - добавлялся без потери содержимого.

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function() {
        window.onresize = insertDiv;
        insertDiv();
    };

function insertDiv(){

    var div = $(".test");   

    var WindowWidth = window.innerWidth;

    if (WindowWidth <= 500){
        $(".test").remove();       
    }
    else{
        $("header").append(div);
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="test"> Рыба </div>
</header>
```

Строка в блоке else не работает.

Вероятно, я не совсем понимаю, что надо сохранять в значение переменной, а что- удалять. Насколько я сейчас знаю, в переменную `div` я сохранил массив, которым описывается DOM-объект, а добавлять надо наверное не этот массив, а HTML-код.

Как бы то ни было, какова причина того, что скрипт не работает?

Полные исходники [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/qjfTUkc6xCcrC) (понадобится локальный сервер, т. к. я сохранил php-структуру своего исходного кода).

Comment: Зачем удалять если можно прятать (причем без скриптов)?

Comment: Потому что свойство `display: none;` является конфликтным для поисковой оптимизации.

Comment: Угадал все буквы - не угадал предложение. Поясните в чем конфликт?

Comment: В том, что поисковики занижают в выдаче сайты, в которых используется CSS-свойство `display: none;`.

Comment: Откуда такая информация?

Comment: На этой самой странице `style="display: none;"` встречается 10 раз. Вы уверены что у данного сайта плохие показатели ранжирования в поисковиках?

Comment: Для этого форума это не страшно, т. к. он уже набрал трафик и контет зарекомендовал себя  в поисковиках. А вот для только что созданных сайтов, которые хотите раскрутить в топ - судя по статьям, имеет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47107/discussion-between-tutankhamun-and-gurebu-bokofu).

Comment: Занижаются не сайты, а вес скрытого контента. То есть что не видит пользователь - то не увидит и поисковик.

Comment: Всяческие рекламные блоки или навигацию скрывать можно совершенно спокойно.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Я не спорю, что Вы правы, но можно попросить Вас обосновать?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu ссылка из приведенной вами же статьи: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521462/search-engine-indexing-of-single-page-applications/31535615#31535615

Comment: @GurebuBokofu надо просто читать глазами, а не тем, чем читал этот пост журналист...

Answer (score -1):

Нужно заменить строку

```
$("header").append(div);
```

на

```
div.clone().appendTo("header");
```

Блок else не работал, потому что append "вырезает" элемент из прошлого места, и вставляет в новое. Если же нам необходимо не переместить элемент, а скопировать, можно воспользоваться методом clone.

Comment: Добавил ссылку на полные исходники. Со своего компа проверил: добавления div не происходт.